# Select an endpoint based on User Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Is it possible to *select* an endpoint based on User Role in Web API?
I'd like to have in one controller a couple of methods for different roles but couldn't find a proper solution to do that.

Edit:
I have a typical UserController with Role-Based Authorization. I'd like to have two methods in the controller eg. SearchForAdmin and SearchForUser (both with URL ../users/search). The method should be selected based on the Role From B2C Token. Any ideas on how could I achieve this?

Comment: Can you share a little code, even if it is not working, on what you are trying to accomplish? Your question right now is kind of vague so not sure what direction to go for a solution.

Comment: @BenMatthews I've updated the question, maybe it is more descriptive now. I didn't start implementing it, because I'm looking for possible solutions first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RequireAuthorization function for endpoints might be what you are looking for. I have not tried this with two different endpoints with the same path and the only difference being two different policies, but I do know that two paths with different require hosts will work. For instance, I know this works for me:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();

                endpoints.MapGet("/Foo", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                }).RequireHost("Something.com");


                endpoints.MapGet("/Foo", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World From Local!");
                }).RequireHost("localhost");
            });
```

I think if you try this, it should work if it stays consistant:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();

                endpoints.MapGet("/Foo", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                }).RequireAuthorization("FirstAuthPolicy", "SecondAuthPolicy");


                endpoints.MapGet("/Foo", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World from a second place!");
                }).RequireAuthorization("ThirdAuthPolicy");
            });
```